# OnClick function isn't working on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I am new to JS. I re-created what i want into JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/t5fq5zjj/

Basically, it's working fine in jsF, but when I apply this into my code, it isn't working. When I click on `.card1` (or whatever) nothing will happen to it. So i want to ask, do I have this right?

```
<head>
    ...
    <!-- js -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    ...
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".icon_card1").click(function () {
        $(".card1bg").css('opacity', '1');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <div class="content">
        <div class="card1">
            <div class="image_card1"></div>
            <div class="icon_card1"><img src="img/arrow.png"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="card1bg">
        <video autoplay  poster="img/background.png" id="bgvid" loop>
            <source src="img/background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

It isn't working in my code, but it is in jsFiddle. Thanks for your time.

**EDIT: I loaded all code to my hosting, so here you can check it: http://hdesign.comehere.cz/**

Comment: The default value for `opacity` is just `1`, you have to set it to something else initially if you want to see anything

Comment: Did you try moving the script tag to the bottom of the body or wrapping it in a `$(document).ready(function() { /*Your code*/ });`? If the script is at the top of the page it may run before the html has been created, binding the click function to nothing.

Comment: Whoops. Just noticed you used the shorthand for .ready(). Ditto to @adeneo first. If you want to see whether your click function is actually running, add a console.log right before the .css(). If it logs to the console, the function is running, then you can narrow it down to the logic.

Comment: I loaded my code on hosting, could you lease check it? I'm stressed out a bit of mistake that I somewhere did...
http://hdesign.comehere.cz/

Comment: Now open the console (F12) and look at all the errors

Comment: Well I hope these errors aren't these errors what I'm looking for..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to test your project on your specified [hosting](http://hdesign.comehere.cz/)
, but I see that jquery file does not load properly (error 404). Try to check your jquery filepath and file location

[image]

Comment: No God damn way... I checked that like 3 times, but in another file directory. Thanks man! You did a lot for me!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your JavaScript code within a document ready function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".card1").click(function () {
        $(".card1_content").css('background', 'red');
    });

    $(".card2").click(function () {
        $(".card1_content").css('background', 'aqua');
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(function () {...` === `$( document ).ready(function() {...`

Comment: That is already in the code. This is a short version of `$(document).ready()`: `$(function () {`

Comment: Thanks! That's helpfull. but didn't solve whole problem :/